# How to convert string with int to string with double?

Tags: java, android, string, int, double

I am building a calculator, for the calculator to work I need to convert all the int numbers to double numbers in my string. For example, if I have this string: 3*8+5/2-4, I want to convert him to: 3.0*8.0+5.0/2.0-4.0.
How can I do this?

EDIT: If I have this string: 3.0*8.0+5.0/2.0-4, I want to convert him to: 3.0*8.0+5.0/2.0-4.0

Comment: Just use `Double#parseDouble` when parsing.

Comment: What if there is a double in a string already, such as 3.4564646? Should it be rounded to one decimal place?

Comment: @JacobG., he cannot parse his string as double since it contains mathematical operators such as +,/,- etc

Comment: @KillerDeath OP would obviously split the `String` first :P

Comment: how I split the String? and what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace string by regex using [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), for example:

```
String regex = "(?<=^|[+/(*)-])(\\d+)(?=[+/(*)-]|$)";

// $1 references to the first captured group ---v
String result1 = "3*8+5/2-4".replaceAll(regex, "$1.0");
//     ^--- "3.0*8.0+5.0/2.0-4.0"

String result2 = "3.0*8+5/2-4.0".replaceAll(regex, "$1.0");
//     ^--- "3.0*8.0+5.0/2.0-4.0"

String result3 = "3.0*(8+5)/(2-4.0)".replaceAll(regex, "$1.0");
//     ^--- "3.0*(8.0+5.0)/(2.0-4.0)"
```

Comment: your solution wouldn't work if there is already exists double number

Comment: @AlexandrLihonosov the OP has said `int` to `double`. have you saw the OP's question?

Comment: yes, this is just my assumption that there is also could be something like this: 3*8+5/2-4+3.5 Why not?

Comment: @AlexandrLihonosov :), it doesn't matter. I admit that doesn't support `double`s.

Comment: if OP uses something like Reverse Polish notation (RPN) to implement the calculator, he could just parse the values from a stack as Double, but without all requirements, we couldn't give a full answer:)

Comment: @AlexandrLihonosov yeah. but this is a off-topic conversation.

Comment: This is not good because if my string is: 2.0+3.0 ==> 2.0.0.0+3.0.0.0

Comment: @GuyRajwan I'm sorry, I was sleeping. How about it now? if no problem I wish you to accept the answer. since if you have any other problem, you can create a new question on stackoverflow, :).

Comment: But if there are a number within parentheses it will not make it.
For example: 2+3*(14-2), need to be: 2.0+3.0*(14.0-2.0).

Comment: @GuyRajwan How about it now?

Comment: @GuyRajwan Not at all. If there is no problem. I hope you to accept my answer ..., :)